# What do [] mean and what does it mean if it is used in an equation?

Tags: soft-question, notation, terminology

What do the square bracket symbols mean? Are they what I hear are "sets"? And when it is in an equation, how is it interpreted?

Here is an example:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}[2x^{2}+y(x)^{2}]=50x+2y(dy/dx)=0$$

Comment: It very much depends on the context. Could you show us a specific instance?

Comment: I found this on http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der05/der05.html:

$$dy/dx[2x^2 + y(x)^2] = 50x + 2y(dy/dx) = 0$$

Comment: That helps out quite a bit. I think the $[\;]$ there are just parentheses by another "name"; you can replace them with $(\;)$ without fear. People will sometimes use $[\;]$ or $\{\;\}$ for this purpose in order to avoid a forest of $)))))$s. It doesn't seem so necessary here.

Comment: The square brackets. Next to dy/dx

Comment: David, since you seem to have some programming background: almost all symbols in math are heavily 'overloaded'. In your example, the squared brackets, they are simply are replacement for the are normal brackets (do you know what 'dx/dx' means? Just checking...) But they can for instance denote a closed interval as in $x\in[0,1]$, or something completely different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes they are the same as parentheses.  Like in $\sum \left[ f(n) - g(n) \right]$ or the expected value $\text{E} \left[ X \right]$.  They may have different meanings if they are specially defined.

Or if you meant $\{ \}$ then these are braces and yes they are often used to represent sets.

There is a lot of [ambiguity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) in the proper nomenclature.

Comment: No, I don't mean those {}, I mean these []

Comment: Show us a context we'll give you an answer. With no context, those could mean anything.

Comment: See my edit ^^^