# What does square brackets around a polynomial mean?

Tags: polynomials, discrete-mathematics

EDIT: *The first paragraph has been indicated as inaccurate, please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406561/62254).*

When we have something like $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$, we
understand that this means the set of polynomials over indeterminate
$x$ where the coefficients are drawn from $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{0,1\}$ with
degree less than $\text{deg} (x^2 + x + 1)$.

So, in this set we can include polynomials like $x$, $x+1$ and 
even $1$, but not $x^2+1$ or $2x+1$. This is okay so far with me.

But in some lecture note ([Rings and fields,
Sergei Silvestrov,
Spring term 2011, Lecture 5](http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklth/personal/ssilvest/AlgebraVT2011/Lecture05Silvestrov.pdf); page 3, Example 1
and subsequent ones) I find representations like,
$\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1) = \{[0], [1], [x], [x + 1]\}$.

I fail to understand why the square brackets have been put around
the polynomials.

Answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104792/what-do-mean-and-what-does-it-mean-if-it-is-used-in-an-equation) says that this depends on the context and
may be same as parentheses or may mean braces to represent sets.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's an equivalence class. All polynomials in $[0]$ are equivalent to the polynomial $0$ up to polynomial multiples of $x^2+x+1$. The nice thing is that the set of resulting equivalence classes inherits the structure of the original space. Hence the name quotient space.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thanks for pointing to the right direction. Discussions in the book by Hungerford cleared things substantially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first three lines aren't accurate: that symbol is for *a field* , represented by that quotient ring, the elements of which can be expressed as polynomials of degree zero or degree one *in one of the roots of the polynomial* $\;x^2+x+1\;$ over $\,\Bbb F_2\,$.

Thus, the elements in that "set" are *not* polynomials but expressions of the form $\,w, w+1,$ , etc., where $\, w^2+w+1=0\pmod 2\,$ , and precisely in order to avoid this confusion is that Silvestrov uses the symbols he does...